# undefined reference on qt sensor

Tags: android, c++, qt, mobile

I am using qt android 5.1.1

and I have problem even I add sensors to pro file what is problem.

Thank you for any comment.
My problem is:

**../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to 'QAccelerometer::QAccelerometer(QObject*)'
../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to 'QSensor::QSensor(QByteArray const&, QObject*)'
../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'QSensor::start()'
../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to 'QSensor::reading() const'
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'libsensor_test.so' failed
../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:22: error: undefined reference to 'QSensor::~QSensor()'
../sensor_test/mainwindow.cpp:22: error: undefined reference to 'QSensor::~QSensor()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

my pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-08-30T14:44:53
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = sensor_test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += sensors

OTHER_FILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/res/layout/splash.xml \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/res/values/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-de/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-el/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-es/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-et/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-fa/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-fr/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-id/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-it/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ja/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ms/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-nb/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-nl/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-pl/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-pt-rBR/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ro/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-rs/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ru/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-zh-rCN/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-zh-rTW/strings.xml \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistro.aidl \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistroCallback.aidl \
    android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity.java \
    android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtApplication.java \
    android/version.xml
```

and my code is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ac=new QAccelerometer(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSensor sensor("QAccelerometer");
    sensor.start();
    QSensorReading *read=sensor.reading();
    ui->lineEdit->setText(read->property("x").value<QString>());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use QtSensors as if it was for Qt 4, i.e. from the Qt Mobility era. Also, I am sure something went wrong at the generation because QtCreator is not supposed to generate anything like that. See the fix below.

You should replace these two lines:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += sensors
```

with:

```
QT += sensors
```

Slightly off-topic, but you should also remove the following line because those two modules are added implicitly by default in Qt 4 as well as Qt 5 used in here.

```
QT       += core gui
```

Here you can find a short snippet which works fine for me:

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    QSensor sensor("QAccelerometer");
    sensor.start();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TARGET = sensor_test
TEMPLATE = app

QT += sensors

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Make sure qmake and nmake are in your PATH, and then run the following command:

`qmake && nmake`